# pyside qt4, alligningment syntax misunderstanding

Tags: python, user-interface, qt4, pyside

I have the following pyside widget code :

```
class NavigationHeadWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self._current_page = 0
        self._last_page = 0

        self._pageination_string = "page %s of %s"
        self._pagination_label = QLabel()
        self._pagination_label.setText(self._pageination_string % (str(self._current_page), str(self._last_page)))


        self.setMinimumWidth(400)
        self._header_buttons_prev = QPushButton("b_prev")
        self._header_buttons_next = QPushButton("b_next")
        self._header_buttons_prev.setText("prev")
        self._header_buttons_next.setText("next")
        self._header_buttons_next.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self._header_buttons_prev.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self._layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self._layout.addWidget(self._header_buttons_prev,Qt.AlignLeft)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._pagination_label,Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._header_buttons_next,Qt.AlignRight)
        self.setLayout(self._layout)
```

which results in :

[image]

I expect the text to centre between the buttons, but it left alligns.

If I comment out the label I get :

[image]

I expect the buttons to be left and right alligned, but they don't seem to do that.

Whats the correct syntax to get the behaviour I want ?

Additionaly How do I get the button to size automatically to the text it contains ? Having to hardcode the size in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r adding the label, and it's centered (it fills all the space between the two buttons). But that doesn't mean that text within the label is also centered automatically. To do that, just add:

```
self._pagination_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```

You can also add [`QSpacerItem`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qspaceritem.html)s between the buttons and the label to get the same effect (by calling the layout's `addStretch` method where you need a stretchable space):

```
self._layout.addWidget(self._header_buttons_prev)
self._layout.addStretch()
self._layout.addWidget(self._pagination_label)
self._layout.addStretch()
self._layout.addWidget(self._header_buttons_next)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I do the same with the buttons to get them to behave ? :D

Comment: I've extended my answer to elaborate a little more on using spacers. This way the buttons would always remain left/right aligned, no matter if the label is there or not.